# Imbalance Dataset Model Predicting only One Class

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I have an imabalance dataset of sentiment analysis on news, this is the distribution:

```
negative: 0
neutral: 1
positive: 2

1    92990
0      158
2       91
Name: sentiment, dtype: int64
```

In order to work with this dataset, I first oversample the dataset with `imblearn` library, so I get this distribution of the classes:

```
1    92990
0    92990
2    92990
Name: sentiment, dtype: int64
```

For my model I'm using a Transformes with attention and a pretrained embedding layer. For the loss funcition I'm using [this](https://github.com/maozezhong/focal_loss_multi_class) focal loss:

And I'm also defining the classes weights for each class with `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(y),y)
```

I have been conbining this methods in order to solve the imbalance issue but none of this seems to be working. The best result I got was using the oversampled dataset, combined with focal loss and setting class weigths, and this is my confusion matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix

y_pred = [np.argmax(p) for p in model.predict(y)]
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true=[np.argmax(i) for i in y], y_pred=y_pred, labels=[0,1,2])

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=[0,1,2]).plot(include_values=True)
```

[image]

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong calculating the confusion matrix but my model doesn't seems to be learning, any suggestions to improve?

EDIT: [Here](https://github.com/dr-alberto/ImbalanceSentiment) is a repo with the datasets and the notebook, feel free to take a look and check what's wrong

Comment: Did you already check, if there is maybe something wrong with your data? E.g. you could reduces your samples to a minimum. E.g. to have one sample per class and then do a test run. If then the model is still not lerning, probably you don't provide the data in a proper format. E.g. maybe you need to pass it through a normalizer etc.

Comment: What does your output really look like? is it maybe always predicting the same value ("probability") for each sample?

Comment: @jottbe The data is an encoding of text so I can't normalize it. And the relation of the data is 1:1000, so undersampling to the minimun will give me a 300-sample dataset.

Comment: @jottbe Yes, it's predicting always the same probability for each sample I pass.